# modify ajax data return

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, datatable

I have a table that is filled in by an ajax request. The return works fine and return my data exactly how it is in my array.

That's the problem. I want to modify this received data and then show it to the user. Don't care if this is done before data is placed into my table or after.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#List').DataTable({
            "ajax": 'ajax/ajax.php',
            "processing": true,
            "columns": [
                {"data": "Date"},
                {"data": "Number"}
            ],
            "columnDefs": [{
                    "targets": -1,
                    "data": "ID",
                    "width": "20px",
                    "className": "text-center"    
                }], "pageLength": 50
        });
    });
```

How would I approach this. My table displays `'number'` as *"+441234"* because that's what is in my pure data but I'd want to take this return and convert is using a different function in js. Convert it to a more readable human form, like *"01234"*. Same for `'date'`. It might return *"01-01-2023"* but I'd want to take this value and turn it into something else like 1st of January, 2024.
How do I take these fields, their data and get to modify it.

Thank you.

Comment: `{data: 'salary', render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number( ',', '.', 0, '$' )}` ....

Comment: Thank you, but what exactly does this do? Does it find "number" inn the datatable and adds $ to it or...?

Comment: This is build in helper, you can see example [here](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers#Number-helper)

Comment: there is no need for you to use it you can write your own. I'll do that in my answer above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [render function](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers#Functions) for any columns that you want to
format/modify.
It doesn't matter how data is populated

> Using [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) is the most common method as it provides absolute control over the data that will be displayed to the end user (this is a regular Javascript function, so you can do virtually anything you wish with the data).

1. The data that is pointed to by columns.data. If columns.data is null, null will be the value given here.
2. The data type being requested by DataTables - this allows the function to support [orthogonal data](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data).
3. The original and full data object or array for the row.

There are also [Build-in helpers](https://datatables.net/manual/data/renderers#Built-in-helpers) for most common types like:
*data*, *datetime*, *number* etc.

> The built in rendering helpers can be accessed under the DataTable.render object (since 1.11) or $.fn.dataTable.render (which is an alias to the same object).

For example in our case we're using `$.fn.dataTable.render.number`

```js
$('#example').dataTable({
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Tiger Nixon",
            "position": "System Architect",
            "deductions": 100.54,
            "salary": "3120",
            "start_date": "01-01-2023",
            "office": "Edinburgh",
            "extn": 5421,
            "Date": "2022-02-02 13:13:13"
        },
        {
            "name": "Garrett Winters",
            "position": "Director",
            "deductions": 222.54,
            "salary": "5300",
            "start_date": "02-02-2022",
            "office": "Edinburgh",
            "extn": "8422",
            "Date": "2022-03-03 12:12:12"
        },
                // ...
    ],
    "columns": [
        {"data": "name"},
        {"data": "position"},
        {"data": "office"},
        {"data": "extn"},
        {"data": "start_date", render: function (data, type, row) {
                const [month, day, year] = data.split('-');
                const date = new Date(+year, +month - 1, +day);
                return date.toLocaleDateString('en-ZA', {
                    day: 'numeric',
                    month: 'long',
                    year: 'numeric'
                });
            }},
        {
            "data": "deductions",
            render: function (data, type, row) {                            
                return "-€ " + data
            }
        },
        {"data": "salary", render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, '$')},
        {"data": "Date", render: function (data, type, row) {
        const [year, month, day, hour, minute, second] = data.split(/[- :]/);
        const date = new Date(+year, +month - 1, +day, +hour, +minute, +second);
        return date.toLocaleDateString('en-ZA', {day: 'numeric', month: 'long', year: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second: 'numeric'});
    }
}
    ]
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<table id="example"></table>
```

Comment: 1) Great stuff! understand it all much better, so wanting to know more. How do I modify this render for more parameters or less. I'd also like to do the same thing but for data that is dat&time. How would I just display time or both? They're 2 different things.

but no luck.

Comment: 2) I've tried:
```{"data": "Date", render: function (data, type, row) {
const [year, month, day, hour, minute, second] = data.split('-', ' ', ':');
const date = new Date(+year, +month - 1, +day, +hour, +minute, +second);
return date.toLocaleDateString('en-ZA', {
day: 'numeric',
month: 'long',
year: 'numeric',
hour: 'numeric',
minute: 'numeric',
second: 'numeric'
});}}```

What am I missing for this

Comment: What if the first data split is set to ```const [date, time] = data.split(' ');``` and then later we can do ```const [year, month, day] = date.split('-');``` and ```const[hour, mintue, second] = time.split(':');``` is that how such a thing could work?

Comment: @Arty sorrry for a late reply, but in you case do you have a field "date" in you data ?

Comment: @Arty I think the problem was in that split. I have rewrited it you can see it in the example

Comment: I see, thank you loads. Yes I have a data field named "Date" which was set to date&time as well as a different data field for a different table that is loaded under the same name "Date." I think I understood it. To reference multiple things that will split the data, the splits are placed into an array first for all 3 things instead of separating by a comma like I first attempted. Will try some variants myself to fully understand how to utilize and control the render function.

Comment: @Arty an up vote will be appreciated

Comment: I'd love to as you've helped me more than a ton of guides can but stackoverlow won't let me. Says I'm not voted high enough yet to upvote others :(

Comment: I see now you can ;)